# Alphabetical Bubble Sort in a STRUCT c programming

Tags: c, string, struct, bubble-sort, alphabetical-sort

I have been trying and trying to get this to work.  I have managed to switch sort 1 name, however then it does not change any other names order. I know that you have to do a string compare in order to do this but I cannot figure it out. Please if you could provide a code snippet to solve this problem.  I am including the whole program here.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Define a doubly linked list type
typedef struct node {
    char name[100];
    int age;
    float weight;
    struct node *next;
} node;

void print_list(node* list, int count) {
    int j = 0;
    node temp;
    // walk the list to print out the contents
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        j = i - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && strcmp(list[j + 1].name, list[j].name) < 0) {
            temp = list[j + 1];
            list[j + 1] = list[j];
            list[j] = temp;
            j--;
        }
    }
    while (list) {
        printf("%s%d\n%f\n", list->name, list->age, list->weight);
        list = list->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

node* new_node(char *value, int a, float w) {
    node* t = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    strcpy(t->name, value);
    t->age = a;
    t->weight = w;
    t->next = NULL;
    return t;
}

node* add(node* list) {
    node* t = list;

    char name[100];
    int a;
    float w;
    printf("Enter name: ");
    fgets(name, 100, stdin);
    printf("Enter age: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Enter weight: ");
    scanf("%f", &w);
    while (getchar() != '\n');

    node* s = new_node(name, a, w);

    // special case: starting with an empty list
    if (t == NULL)
        return s;

    s->next = list;
    return s;
}

int getChoice() {
    int ch;
    printf("1. Add a Record\n2. Display All Records\n");
    printf("3.Quit\nEnter choice: ");
    scanf("%d", &ch);
    while (getchar() != '\n');
    return ch;
}

int main() {
    node* my_list = NULL;

    int ch;
    int count = 0;
    while ((ch = getChoice()) != 3) {
        if (ch == 1) {
            my_list = add(my_list);
            count++;
        }
        else if (ch == 2) {
            print_list(my_list, count);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: Sorts 3 names for me. How is it not working?

Comment: I don't see any sorting capability here, it just adds a new node to the front of the list

Comment: @Mark So I am using names John, Sergio, Albert in that order. It moves Albert to the top of the list, but Sergio stays second and John is 3rd.

Comment: That result makes sense based on the code

Comment: I think you could find some nice node sorting algorithms if you do a small amount of research

Comment: This line does not make sense: `temp = list[j + 1];` . When walking a linked list, you need to use the `next` pointer, and not treat it as an array.  `temp = temp->next;`

Comment: @liam Hi Liam thank you for your input. But as I have stated I have spent a lot of time trying to fix this to no success. Hence why I posted on here asking for help (code snippet) if possible, for you to just say research and make comments like results make sense based on your code (snarky) is not really helpful. But thank you for taking time out of your busy day to read everything, obviously know a solution and provide the answer google it.

Comment: It will take more than that line.  No access with brackets `[]` will be valid.  The while loop to print the list is correct.  Use that same loop for printing the contents.

Comment: Your structure can't be a doubly-linked list as the comment says because it has only one pointer, not two.  Using indexing on a list is unlikely to work — the data isn't organized as an array; it is a list.  It's easier to sort an array, but you need an array to be able to sort it.

Comment: Brackets only work on arrays (unless they have been overloaded).  You are trying to use the brackets to do your sorting.  You could do that if create an array of the node pointers and then sort the array according to your compare function.  Is that what you were thinking?

Comment: Then how would I go about comparing the names in the list so they are sorted if it is not used as an array?

Comment: You can allocate an array of the appropriate size and copy the list nodes into the array, then sort the array (easiest). Or you can leave the list nodes in place and just swap their data payloads. Or you can make the list a real doubly-linked list and fix up the `prev` and `next` pointer in the sort (pain in the neck)

Comment: The requirements for this program is that I cannot use an array. So i guess my only option is to make it a doubly-linked list. How do I got about doing this, as I have never done this (i am a student and this is our first attempt at a linked list).

Comment: Perhaps it would be best if you stated *all* of the requirements first.

Comment: @ender987 I did not mean to be snarky at all, sorry about that. I just came back from completing an example for you, I usually give a detailed explanation but now I'm feeling less helpful. Please try to avoid comments like that in the future as they don't help anyone.

Comment: @liamcomp thank you for giving an example.  I really do appreciate it (no sarcasm).  However I feel my response was on par as yours. But as you have extended an olive branch allow me to apologize, I am sorry if it upset you or was uncalled for.

Comment: @mark apologies, I did not know it would have made a difference as I thought there was just a small error in my code and a simple fix, next time I will include all requirements. Write a program that creates the following struct (you can give it whatever name you want):
char name[100];
int age;
float weight;
Create the following menu system:

Add a Record
Display All Records
Quit

you will insert the record into the linked list which will be alphabetically ordered by name (first letter of full name)
This program will not use an array, but it will use a linked list of structs.

Comment: Well, then, if you have no formal requirement to sort the list after the fact, then by all means insert them in sort order to start with.

Comment: lol do you mean ask the user to enter it in alphabetically? I thought about doing that like an hour ago because I was fed up

Comment: No, just insert them in order in the list, like in the current posted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this to add the node to the sorted list:

```
node * add_node_to_sort_list(node * list, node * newNode)
{
    /* should the node be inserted as the head? */
    if( list == NULL || strncmp(list->name, newNode->name, 100) < 0 )
    {
        newNode->next = list;
        return newNode;
    }

    /* search for the location the node should be at */
    while(list->next != NULL && strncmp(list->next->name, newNode->name) > 0 )
    {
        /* move to the next node */
        list = list->next;
    }

    /* we have found the spot to insert the node */
    newNode->next = list->next;
    list->next = newNode;

    return list;
}
```

Using this to update your code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Define a doubly linked list type
typedef struct node {
    char name[100];
    int age;
    float weight;
    struct node *next;
} node;

void print_list(node* list) {

    // walk the list to print out the contents
    while(list != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s%d\n%f\n", list->name, list->age, list->weight);
        list = list->next;
    }
}

node* new_node(char *value, int a, float w) {
    node* t = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    strcpy(t->name, value);
    t->age = a;
    t->weight = w;
    t->next = NULL;
    return t;
}

node * add_node_to_sort_list(node * list, node * newNode)
{
    /* should the node be inserted as the head? */
    if( list == NULL || strncmp(list->name, newNode->name, 100) > 0 )
    {
        newNode->next = list;
        return newNode;
    }

    /* search for the location the node should be at */
    while(list->next != NULL && strncmp(list->next->name, newNode->name, 100) < 0 )
    {
        /* move to the next node */
        list = list->next;
    }

    /* we have found the spot to insert the node */
    newNode->next = list->next;
    list->next = newNode;

    return list;
}

node* add(node* list) {

    char name[100];
    int a;
    float w;
    printf("Enter name: ");
    fgets(name, 100, stdin);
    printf("Enter age: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Enter weight: ");
    scanf("%f", &w);
    while (getchar() != '\n');

    node* s = new_node(name, a, w);

    return add_node_to_sort_list(list, s);
}

int getChoice() {
    int ch;
    printf("1. Add a Record\n2. Display All Records\n");
    printf("3.Quit\nEnter choice: ");
    scanf("%d", &ch);
    while (getchar() != '\n');
    return ch;
}

int main() {
    node* my_list = NULL;

    int ch;
    while ((ch = getChoice()) != 3) {
        if (ch == 1) {
            my_list = add(my_list);
        }
        else if (ch == 2) {
            print_list(my_list);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: going to try this now

Comment: Are you required to return a sorted list, or to use a bubble sort to sort the items?  This is a great solution if you are not required to use a bubble sort algorithm.

Comment: No not required to use a bubble sort, I just thought it was the only way. I'm still trying to get it to work. I don't think I'm doing it correctly, I have tried to copy and paste it into my code, but not sure where to. I'm still experimenting, but I'm tired and I think im now just goings in circles

Comment: After you create the new node. you should be able to do something like ‘return add_node_to_sort_list(list, s);’

Comment: Thanks Liam, I am sure you solution would work for me if I was more skilled and better understood linked lists. I have been unable to get it to work, and my no later than due date is coming up so I am just going to have to turn it in as is. Thanks for your help I'm marking the answer as correct considering people seem to agree with your solution. Thanks again.

Comment: @ender987 please see edit with (probably) working code

Comment: It works perfectly. I'm lookling through and I was trying to return add_node_to_sort_list(list, s); in my print (yes i know its void, but i am leh tired). very elegant solution as Gardener said. Clearly I am going to need to spend more time on linked lists and string compares before my exam.  Thanks again Liam apologies for my earlier outburst.